# Poll a Future in Scala.js

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future, scala.js

I have a Future in a cross-platform JVM / JS application. The future is polled following way in JVM:

```
val load = Future(loadSometing())

if (load.isCompleted) {
  val loaded = Await.result(load, Duration.Inf)
  // now process it
}
```

This cannot work with Scala.js, as Scala.js does not implement `Await`. In my case however I am not using Await to wait, only to get the result I know is already there. I know a proper solution is to make the code fully async and to perform the processing in the `Future` handler (map or onComplete), but even known it is not a proper way, can `Future` result be polled somehow in Scala.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Future.value` to poll a `Future` without waiting/blocking:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f = Future { 42 }
println(f.value)

js.timers.setTimeout(500) {
  println(f.value)
}
```

will print

```
None
Some(Success(42))
```

[Fiddle here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/73DQWWC/0)